# Validating whatsapp webhooks Payloads in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, webhooks, whatsapi

I'm trying to validate the contents of a webhook payload from the whatsapp webhooks using the steps in the .[Facebook developer docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started),

I dont understand what this mean

> Please note that we generate the signature using an escaped unicode version of the payload, with lowercase hex digits. If you just calculate against the decoded bytes, you will end up with a different signature. For example, the string äöå should be escaped to \u00e4\u00f6\u00e5.

that why I've always got false when comparing hash value And i want to make it in php/laravel.

after sometimes i tried to use

```
            $knownSignature = (new UnicodeString($request->getContent()))->normalize(UnicodeString::NFKC);
```

and

```
$knownSignature = Str::ascii($request->getContent());
```

But still doesnt match.
event when i tried to convert äöå it still outputting \u00e4\u00f6\u00e5

This is [Symfoni](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/string.html#methods-added-by-codepointstring-and-unicodestring) and [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-str-ascii) docs for escape unicode string

Comment: check this [webhook example in nodejs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/sample-app-endpoints)

Comment: Why are you calling this `$knownSignature`, the request content _is not_ the signature, it is only the input data for the signature _calculation_. And you should use the actual, raw data you received for this - and not be trying to manipulate it using any normalize or ascii methods.

Comment: 1. Generate a SHA256 signature using the payload and your app's App Secret.
2. Compare your signature to the signature in the X-Hub-Signature-256 header (everything after sha256=). If the signatures match, the payload is genuine.
that's what writen in the docs, so take the payloads to normalize it hashing it, and compare it to the signature in the header

Comment: @turivishal it doesn't give an example to validate the payloads

Comment: @CBroe [Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73329296/using-symfony-unicodestring-on-laravel) thats my function please correct me

Comment: Like I said - use the _raw_ POST body data you received as input data for your signature calculation, and not anything that you _modified_ in any way. If `$request->getContent()` doesn't give you access to the raw body, then read it from `php://input`.

Comment: @CBroe thanks, I've changed it to `php://input` , but still doesn't get the right value

Comment: _"I've changed it to php://input"_ doesn't really tell us what _exactly_ you did now. Show updated code.

Comment: @CBroe [Code](https://pastebin.com/8xPtHW1C) this is the new code

Comment: Okay, and what part of _use the **raw** data_ don't you understand? Why are you still applying `UnicodeString::normalize` to it?

Comment: @CBroe because in the facebooks docs said this _Please note that we generate the signature using an escaped unicode version of the payload, with lowercase hex digits. If you just calculate against the decoded bytes, you will end up with a different signature. For example, the string äöå should be escaped to \u00e4\u00f6\u00e5_

Comment: The request body content _is_ the "escaped unicode version of the payload." Facebook is telling you there, that you should not use any decoded and then re-encoded version of this, but the actual data you received, without _any_ further manipulation.

Comment: @CBroe is that mean the signature in the header is the escaped version of the payload ? so to validate it we need to escape the payload first before hashing it ?
Or what? I'm sorry my english is not that good

Comment: The signature from the header, is the value you need to compare your calculated signature to. _"so to validate it we need to escape the payload first before hashing it ?"_ - no. Use it _exactly_ as you have received it, do not manipulate _anything_ about it.

Comment: @CBroe I've tried that too, after getting the raw body like [this](https://pastebin.com/8xPtHW1C) but it still returns false/could not verify

Comment: Well then do a bit of debugging, and check what `$data_body` contains here now to begin with. And $known_signature and $signature_parts[1] as well.

Comment: @CBroe I've been debugging it the content of `$request->getContent` is raw Request, but it still gives the invalid signature, i used [this](https://modess.io/2013/07/25/get-raw-post-data-in-laravel/) as a reference too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done just like @CBroe said it did not work in my previous function, but when I remake it like this its works

```
protected function validatePayloads(string $waSignature,string $payloads){
    $receivedSignature = explode('=', $waSignature)[1];

    $generatedSignature = hash_hmac(
        'sha256',
        $payloads,
        config('app.app_secret')
    );

    if($receivedSignature == $generatedSignature){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Just like @CBroe said you need to hash the raw request

Comment: Hi @blue-moon. Can you paste how you are getting $payloads ? That is the most crucial part. Using `request->getContent()` directly gives different hash.

Comment: As mentioned by @felixfrey, make sure you are using AppSecret & not WebHook verification secret that you created. request->getContent() does work properly.

Answer (score 2):

The answer @Blue Moon gave does compare strings with the === operator, which is not safe to do when comparing user-provided strings / hashes. You should use `hash_equals()` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php) to avoid timing attacks!

Also, @Patel TiLAK - using $request->getContent() does work, maybe you did not use the correct `App Secret`?

```
private function verifySignature(Request $request)
{
    $body = $request->getContent();
    $requestHash = 'sha256=' . hash_hmac('sha256', $body, config('services.whatsapp.app_secret'));

    if (!hash_equals($requestHash, $request->header('X-Hub-Signature-256'))) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @felixfrey. I was using WebHook verification secret rather than AppSecret hence it was not working. Its working now :)